# Add new row if conditions are met then sum columns

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to come up with a process that loops through the entire name row and combines the Person's "Total" rows and sums all the columns together.

In the example image below I would like all of Person 1's values to be totaled into 1 row labeled "Person 1 total". Then delete the previous "Total" rows. Then move onto person 2.

[image]

Here is my code below, I seem to have an issue with it forever looping and creating rows, because it runs for at least 10 minutes and then runs out of memory.

```
Sub Sum()

Dim r As Range
Dim cell As Range


Application.ScreenUpdating = False


'Set r = Range("B2:B15000") 'ACTUAL RANGE
Set r = Range("B2:B20") 'EXAMPLE RANGE
For Each cell In r
    If cell.Value = cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value And cell.Value <> cell.Offset(1, 0).Value Then
        cell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
        cell.Offset(1, 0).Value = cell.Value
    End If
Next


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Range("A2").Select 
End Sub
```

I haven't been able to begin trying to sum all of the rows yet, just stuck on creating rows but if any of you could help me out that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was occurring because, after inserting the new row, you set the value in column B in that new row to the value from the previous row.  When your code then went through the loop again, it would be looking at the newly inserted value, deciding that its value was the same as the previous row but different to the next row, and therefore inserting yet another new row.  Ad infinitum.

Try starting from the bottom and working upward:

```
Sub Sum()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim myRow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'lastRow = 20
    '  or
    lastRow = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For myRow = lastRow To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(myRow, "B").Value = Cells(myRow - 1, "B").Value And Cells(myRow, "B").Value <> Cells(myRow + 1, "B").Value Then
            Rows(myRow + 1).EntireRow.Insert
            Cells(myRow + 1, "B").Value = Cells(myRow, "B").Value
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Range("A2").Select
End Sub
```

---

To perform the underlying task that you want to do, you may actually be better off using a flow that goes something like the following **pseudo-code**

```
r = 2
lastRow = 15000 'or whatever

Do While r < lastRow

    various totals = various totals + corresponding values from row r

    If name on row r = name on row r+1 Then
        delete row r
        lastRow = lastRow - 1
    Else
        values on row r = corresponding totals
        set all totals = 0
        r = r + 1
    End If

Loop
```